# cordova: accordion list for html

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I need a accordion list for the html code below. I just want it to be able to open (expand) when click on the 'Technical'. When click again, it will close(collapse).

This is my html code

```
      <!-- Techincal -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col boldText">Technical</div>
        </div>

      <!--List-->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="row centerized">
          <div class="col col-40"></div>
          <div class="col col-30">Min</div><div class="col col-30">Max</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-40">Tech spec</div>
          <div class="col col-30"><input type="number" placeholder="0" ng-model="searchQuery.techMin"></div>
          <div class="col col-30"><input type="number" placeholder="5"  ng-model="searchQuery.techMax"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-40">Radius</div>
          <div class="col col-30"><input type="number" placeholder="-1000" ng-model="searchQuery.radiusMin"></div>
          <div class="col col-30"><input type="number" placeholder="1000" ng-model="searchQuery.radiusMax"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I have no javascript code just simple html. It is written in ionic/cordova. How make it a simple preset collapsable and expandable when click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, without extra modules. Just a simple solution to toggle some content. Animation can be done using CSS if needed. This is just to get you started with your initial question.

**VIEW**

```
  <!-- Techincal -->
  <div class="item">

    <div class="row">
      <div style="padding:10px; background: gray;" class="col boldText" ng-click="vm.toggleContainer()">Technical</div>
    </div>

    <!--List-->
    <div class="item" style="margin-top:25px;" ng-if='vm.showTechnicalDetails'>
      <div class="row centerized">
        <div class="col col-40"></div>
        <div class="col col-30">Min</div>
        <div class="col col-30">Max</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-40">Tech spec</div>
        <div class="col col-30">
          <input type="number" placeholder="0" ng-model="searchQuery.techMin">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-30">
          <input type="number" placeholder="5" ng-model="searchQuery.techMax">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-40">Radius</div>
        <div class="col col-30">
          <input type="number" placeholder="-1000" ng-model="searchQuery.radiusMin">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-30">
          <input type="number" placeholder="1000" ng-model="searchQuery.radiusMax">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

**JS Angular part (`vm` approach)**

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)

function MainController() {

  var vm = this;
  vm.toggleContainer = toggleContainer;
  vm.showTechnicalDetails = false;

  function toggleContainer() {
    vm.showTechnicalDetails = !vm.showTechnicalDetails;
  }

}
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/Ln2dgmer/

**JS Angular part (`$scope`approach)**

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)

function MainController($scope) {

  $scope.showTechnicalDetails = false;
  $scope.toggleContainer = function(){
    $scope.showTechnicalDetails = !$scope.showTechnicalDetails;
  }

}
```

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/Ln2dgmer/3/

Comment: desmedt Is it possible to change the function in $scope as it is in ionic framework. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure, please have a look at for the `$scope`approach. https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/Ln2dgmer/3/. If this answer helps your problem please also indicate that on the question.

Comment: It is actually query data from database. Your solution will able to search if `'technical'` is click and expand. It will not search if the `'technical'` is collapsible. Is it possible to make it able to search for both condition, just the content is hide/shown.

Comment: it happen for the first time only, the second time it will work regardless hide or shown @daan.desmedt

Comment: Sorry @behappy but I don't understand what you are trying to do... Can you please explain more humanized?

Comment: Sorry @daan desmedt . I put it in jsfiddle but it do not show properly. It always change from `ion-plus` to `ion-minus` after I click search and show the result page. https://jsfiddle.net/fhmLLa4u/4/ ,Sorry, first time using it and unable to show the + and _ sign. I follow this example http://jsfiddle.net/shengoo/6b0y3tar/ . I want it only change if the user click on to expand and collapse the list.

Comment: Your code is incomplete - i've added the missing `ionic` resources here : https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/fhmLLa4u/6/. Unfortunately I can't help you any further since there are missing pieces of code.

Comment: could you explain in details `$scope.showTechnicalDetails = false;
  $scope.toggleContainer = function(){
    $scope.showTechnicalDetails = !$scope.showTechnicalDetails;
  }` for this part? Thanks @daan desmedt

Comment: When ever we click the div with `ng-click="vm.toggleContainer()` the `$scope` value (to show the content container) is toggled. When `$scope.showTechnicalDetails` is `true` the container is shown, when `false` the container is hidden.

Comment: How about `$scope.showTechnicalDetails = !$scope.showTechnicalDetails;`?

Comment: It's just reversing the boolean value. `true` becomes `false` and vice versa. It's the same as `$scope.showTechnicalDetails = ($scope.showTechnicalDetails) ? false : true;`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods to solve this, i find this method as per your requirement

> Your HTML code

```
 <!-- Techincal -->
      <ul>
        <li  class="item-stable item-icon-right" 
            ng-click="toggleGroup(0)" 
            ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(0)}">
            <button class="item-text-center item-text-wrap">Techincal </button>
        </li>
        <div   class="item-accordion"
                ng-show="isGroupShown(0)">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!--List-->
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row centerized">
                                <div class="col col-40"></div>
                                <div class="col col-30">Min</div><div class="col col-30">Max</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col col-40">Tech spec</div>
                                <div class="col col-30"><input type="number" placeholder="0" ng-model="searchQuery.techMin"></div>
                                <div class="col col-30"><input type="number" placeholder="5"  ng-model="searchQuery.techMax"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col col-40">Radius</div>
                                <div class="col col-30"><input type="number" placeholder="-1000" ng-model="searchQuery.radiusMin"></div>
                                <div class="col col-30"><input type="number" placeholder="1000" ng-model="searchQuery.radiusMax"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
```

> Here is your js code

```
<script>
   $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
        if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
            $scope.shownGroup = null;
        } else {
            $scope.shownGroup = group;
        }
    };
    $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
            return $scope.shownGroup === group; 
};
</script>
```

Comment: As a remark - Don't use directive functions (as you do for `ng-show="isGroupShown(0)"` for checking values - this makes the digest cycle heavier. Instead set them to a scope variable.

Comment: Thanks @daan.desmedt